# A brief explanation on who the separatists in the Star Wars prequels are and their relations with the Empire?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, the-phantom-menace, attack-of-the-clones

To my understanding, the Galactic Republic has a group of separatists under Count Dooku, and they later on become the Galactic Empire?

Comment: No, they were defeated by the Republic. The Republic turned into the Empire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Confederacy_of_Independent_Systems)

> The Confederacy of Independent Systems (CIS), also known as the
> Separatist Alliance, the Separatist State, or simply as the
> Separatists, was a galactic government that began as a loose
> separatist movement which stood opposed to the Galactic Republic. In
> the wake of the Naboo Crisis, various planetary and sectorial
> governments, as well as some galactic mega-corporations, declared
> their independence from the Republic who refused to comply with the
> excessive taxation and corruption that plagued it, resulting in the
> secession crisis and a massive military build up in the lead-up to
> war.

In short, the relatively reasonable goals of the Separatist Alliance (e.g. lower taxes and increased independence from the Galactic Republic) were co-opted by Sidious/Palpatine. He and Dooku ordered two large armies and gave one to each side; a gigantic droid army built on Geonosis for the Separatists and a clone army bred on Kamino was given to the Republic.

The Jedi were tricked into commanding the Clone Army and at an opportune moment Sidious killed the Jedi (using the clone troops) *and* the Separatist leadership (using Darth Vader). This caused the Droid armies to shut down and put the Clone Armies under Palpatine's direct control.

With the Jedi dead, the droid armies destroyed and the Separatists decapitated, Palpatine had no-one to oppose him in turning the Republic into The "Empire" that we see in episodes IV, V and VI.

Comment: Why did Sidous not combine the droids and the clones into a single powerful army after he seized power?

Comment: @DylanChen - He didn't need to. In reality, the Clone Army was only needed to oppose the droid army. And the droid army was only needed to trick the Jedi into putting themselves into a vulnerable position.

Comment: @DylanCzenski If he had, it would have become much, much more obvious that he had manipulated the Clone Wars himself. He became Emperor by convincing the Republic senate that he was their great hero.

Answer (score 4):

The Separatists were used as pawns by Darth Sidious to gain power. He systematically used them to gain more and more power throughout the prequels.

He sends the Trade Federation to attack Naboo, where he was a senator. Because of the Chancellor's unwillingness to take swift action, Palpatine convinced Queen Amidala to put in a vote of "no confidence" against the current chancellor. This resulted in him being stripped of the position and Palpatine taking his place (with some Sith tricks).

The machine union was also part of the Separatists. They built the droid army, which Chancellor Palpatine used as reason for needing a clone army (one that he had already set into motion long before making his power move). The clone army was then used to exterminate the Jedi and also begin the makings of the Galactic Empire's stormtrooper regime.

After Palpatine was in complete control of everything, he had Vader kill all the Separatists to clean up any remaining evidence of what he had done to gain power, as well as to end the perceived conflict which he used to justify the creation of an Empire.